# TCP Java Android Server / C# Windows Client Communication not working

Tags: java, c#, android, server, tcp

I am currently trying to set up an App for an Android Device, which can communicate with Devices in the same Network via TCP connection. Said Devices run on Windows and therefore I created a simple C# TCP Client program to connect to the TCP Server. The connection gets established when the Server App is already running and a Client tries to connect to it. Both sides (Server/Client) confirm that the connection got established. When I send data from the server via DataOutputStream back to the client, the client confirms, that he got the message. But when I try to send data from the client and try to read it on the server via InputStreamReader the server never reacts to incoming messages.

Below lies the Java Android server code:

```
public class TCPServer {

    public enum ServerCommands { TURN_OFF }

    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static final Handler HANDLER = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    private static final int SERVERPORT = 5040;
    private static final HashMap<InetAddress, ServerClientCommunicationThread> connectedClientThreads = new HashMap<>();

    private interface OnUpdateUIListener {
        void onShowStatus(String status);
    }

    private static OnUpdateUIListener listener;

    public static void InitServer(Consumer<String> showStatus) {

         listener = new OnUpdateUIListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShowStatus(String status) {
                // Use the handler so we're not trying to update the UI from the bg thread
                HANDLER.post(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        showStatus.accept(status);
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        Thread serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
        serverThread.start();
    }

    public static void OnStop(){
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void SendMessageToClient(InetAddress clientIP, ServerCommands action){
        ServerClientCommunicationThread clientThread = connectedClientThreads.get(clientIP);
        listener.onShowStatus("Trying to send Data to client!");
        if (clientThread != null)
            clientThread.getHandler().sendEmptyMessage(action.ordinal());
    }

    private static class ServerThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            Socket socket = null;
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            boolean error = false;
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !error) {
                try {
                    listener.onShowStatus("Start listening for clients!");
                    socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    listener.onShowStatus("Found client: " + socket.getInetAddress());

                    ClientServerCommunicationThread clientCommThread = new ClientServerCommunicationThread(socket);
                    new Thread(clientCommThread).start();

                    ServerClientCommunicationThread serverCommThread = new ServerClientCommunicationThread("CommThread", socket);
                    new Thread(serverCommThread).start();

                    connectedClientThreads.put(serverCommThread.clientSocket.getInetAddress(), serverCommThread);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    listener.onShowStatus("Could not establish client connection: " + e);
                    error = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private static class ServerClientCommunicationThread extends HandlerThread {

        private DataOutputStream outputStream;
        private Socket clientSocket;
        private Handler commHandler;

        public ServerClientCommunicationThread(String name, Socket clientSocket) {
            super(name);
            try {
                this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
                this.outputStream = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                listener.onShowStatus("ERROR: could not open ReaderStream: " + e);
            }
        }

        @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
        @Override
        protected void onLooperPrepared(){
            commHandler = new Handler(){
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg){
                    try {
                        outputStream.write(msg.what);
                        listener.onShowStatus("Sent action: " + msg.what);
                        outputStream.flush();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        listener.onShowStatus("Could not send data to client: " + clientSocket.getInetAddress() + " " + e);
                    }
                }
            };
            listener.onShowStatus("Start Server Communication Thread");
        }

        public Handler getHandler(){
            return commHandler;
        }
    }


    private static class ClientServerCommunicationThread extends Thread {

        private BufferedReader input;
        private final Socket clientSocket;

        public ClientServerCommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket){
            super();
            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
            try{
                this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                listener.onShowStatus("ERROR: could not open ReaderStream: " + e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run(){
            listener.onShowStatus("Start Client Communication Thread");
            boolean connectionStable = true;
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && connectionStable) {
                try {
                    String read = input.readLine();
                    //It never reaches this debug message!
                    listener.onShowStatus("Received message: " + read);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    listener.onShowStatus("ERROR: could not read message: " + e);
                    connectionStable = false;
                }
            }

            try {
                input.close();
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below lies my C# client code.
I am using the SuperSimpleTCP library for my C# code.

```
namespace SimpleTCPProgram
{
    internal class TCPClient
    {
        private static SimpleTcpClient tcpClient;
        private static int udpPort = 5041;
        private static int tcpPort = 5040;

        private static string macAddr;

        enum ServerCommands { TURN_OFF = 0 }


        // Main Method
        static public void Main(String[] args)
        {
            InitTCPClient("192.168.1.4");
            Console.ReadKey();
            tcpClient.Send("Hello there");

            Console.WriteLine("Sent data: " + tcpClient.Statistics.SentBytes.ToString());

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void InitTCPClient(string serverIP)
        {
            try
            {
                tcpClient = new SimpleTcpClient(serverIP + ":" + tcpPort);
                tcpClient.Events.Connected += Events_Connected;
                tcpClient.Events.Disconnected += Events_Disconnected;
                tcpClient.Events.DataReceived += Events_DataReceived;

                tcpClient.Connect();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private static void Events_Connected(object sender, ConnectionEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connected to Server: " + e.IpPort);
        }

        private static void Events_Disconnected(object sender, ConnectionEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private static void Events_DataReceived(object sender, SuperSimpleTcp.DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            string dataString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Data);
            Console.WriteLine("Received Data: " + dataString);
            
            ServerCommands serverCommand = (ServerCommands)int.Parse(dataString);
            switch (serverCommand)
            {
                case ServerCommands.TURN_OFF:
                    var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("shutdown", "/s /t 0");
                    psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
                    Process.Start(psi);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Wireshark seems to confirm that the message has been sent to the server.
It even catches a message sent back by the server to the client in response.
I am testing this on a test-router which doesn't have internet access and no firewall active.
My server app has the following permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" tools:ignore="ManifestOrder"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

TLDR: My Android java server doesn't get any C# client messages sent via TCP connection.

Comment: See if connection is still connected.  From cmd.exe >Netstat -a  you may of closed connection.  If you are  shutting down the shutdown may start to take affect before server response to message.

Comment: ^^ That said, it's maybe not the best of ideas to _start_ with implementing remote shutdown?

Comment: i am currently not sending the shutdown command from server to client. the only communication happening is sending a simple "Hello there" message from client to server, which is not being noticed by the server

Comment: Does the "Found client..." Message appear?

Comment: the ServerClientCommunicationThread is being opened upon initial connection establishment. But the actual message sending is only happening when the handler inside it gets called from outside the thread. You can see that happening in the SendMessageToClient method , which i am currently not calling at all

Comment: Ah, ... you do a `ReadLine` - but you never _send_ a NewLine.

Comment: "Does the "Found client..." Message appear? " Yes it is

Comment: Try `tcpClient.Send("Hello there\n");`

Comment: Try tcpClient.Send("Hello there\n"); – 
Fildor
YES thats it. now its working. but why?

Comment: `readLine` will block until it encounters a NewLine char in the input. And the TcpClient's `Send` Method does not automatically append a NewLine. So by adding a `\n` to the String, you do that manually.

Comment: Basically, what the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) say: _"Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), a carriage return followed immediately by a line feed, or by reaching the end-of-file (EOF)."_ (I know it's Java SE docs... )

Comment: ah i see. hm there has to be a better way than using readLine then...

Comment: Absolutely. You could (and should) probably come up with and implement a protocol, where you have decent delimiters etc. Or pick an existing protocol if that suites your needs. Your code _will_ get significantly more complex, though.

Comment: Rolling your own will of course be quite tedious. But if this is a "try & learn" Project, it's absolutely worth it and can actually be fun to fall into each and every trap there is with inventing and implementing protocols.